# Merge audio files

Tags: php, linux, audio, sox

I want to merge more than one Audio files. I use linux `sox` command.

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/sox 1.wav 2.wav combined.wav ');
```

It work fine and generate combined audio file.

my 1.wav and 2.wav files length are 90 seconds, 50 seconds respectively. here this `sox` command generate combined.wav with length 140 seconds.

Here, in 2.wav first 20 seconds of audio is already available in 1.wav of last 20 seconds audio. So i want to merge such that **my combined.wav should be 120 seconds**. So, I want to remove duplicated audio in combined.wav which is in last some seconds in 1.wav and in start some seconds in 2.wav.

**Here I just give second as only for examples. In my actual code seconds are not fixed. I have just only audio files.**

**Is there any way done this with Linux command or PHP classes?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use

-p option to sox is used for piping

-p option to sox is used for piping - basically, it tells sox to use stdout as the output. Using - as the input to the second sox is actually saying input is stdin (which happens to be the stdout of the previous sox, as we are piping with |). pad 30 0 tells pad 20 seconds at the beginning and 0 seconds at the end.

Since you want to pad first 30 second of second audio

```
$ sox 1.wav  | sox - -m 2.wav -p pad 30 0 combined.wav
```

Comment: Ya you are right Can you help me little bit more.Here I just give second as only for examples. In my actual code seconds are not fixed. I have just only audio files.

Comment: @Naveen an explanation of what you're doing would probably help more than spoon feeding

Comment: is the amount delay between files , is not known by you and random?

Comment: @NaveenKumar its unknown for me. every time audio file is different and padding time also different

Comment: if you can calculate the padding time instead of 30, use the variable in that place

Comment: Ya i have that logic but how to calculate this ? I don't know about linux command.

Comment: Then your problem, would be solved by building the command as above replacing 30 , with what delay you get and executing it

Answer (score 0):

@Naveen Kumar: -p option of Sox : Run in  preview mode and run fast. This will somewhat speed up SoX when the output format has a different number of channels and a different rate than the input file.